# Correlation between 3 continuous variables

Tags: plot, statistics, correlation, analysis, spss

I am pretty new to statistics, and I am stuck with this.
I have the data containing birth weight, length of baby and head circumference.
I need to provide an answer to how are they related.
How can I do that?

Thank you very much :)

I was thinking doing the Pearson test between each pair.

Comment: Welcome to Stack-Overflow! This is a statistical question and not about programming, and is therefore off topic here. You should try to post it on [Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could

1. First just start with finding the correlations (Pearson or any other kind) between the pairs.
2. Then You probably would want to plot them on X & Y axes (scatter plot) for each pair to visualize. In the plot you will see if higher values of one variable are associated (or not) with the other variable's higher values.
   Lastly, you could also check
3. Each variable's distribution using a box plot. This will tell you the mean, median and the standard deviation.